# topf- and botf-equivalent (in tabout-stata) for outreg2

Tags: tables, stata

I am wondering if there is a topf- and botf-equivalent (used in tabout-stata) for outreg2? What I wanna do is tell stata to insert some TeX code into the top and bottom of file when it outputs the regression table.

Is tex (fragment) helpful?

Sample code for tabout:

```
tabout Produce_Full_SR Sus_Sec_in_AR Full_SR_Assured C_or_S C_or_S1 EnergyDisclosures EmissionsDisclosures WaterDisclosures WasteDisclosures Sector if STI_30==0 using "$tables\overview by sector and size.tex", ///
        c( freq ) f( 0c ) clab(freq) mi ///
        h3(& \multicolumn{13}{c}{\textbf{non-STI30 companies}} \\) cl1(2-14) cl2(2-2 3-3 4-4 5-5 6-6 7-7 8-8 9-9 10-10 11-11 12-12 13-13 14-14) ///
        rep ///
        style(`i') bt font(bold) ///
        topf(top.tex)  topstr(20.5cm)
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is on topic here.

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if you gave us a Minimum Working Example with a standard Stata data set, e.g. 'auto'.